# os_log - use of unresolved identifier error

Tags: ios, logging, swift4, oslog

I'm trying to use the new os_log API, by logging a simple statement:
os_log("Hello")

And I get an error for os_log:
Use of unresolved identifier 'os_log'

I also tried wrapping it in a block, like this

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    let foo: StaticString = "Something happened."
    os_log(foo)
}
```

And I still get the same error. I would like to use this in Swift 4.

I looked for possible frameworks that might be required, and found no likely candidates.

I found no solution from these links either:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because you forgot to

```
import os
```

at the start of this file.

Comment: Also that is not how to use `os_log`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53403036/problems-with-unified-logging-staticstring-customstringconvertible-and-descrip for a complete example.

Comment: For Objective-C, it is `#import <os/log.h>`, correct?

Comment: Probably. I could have said `import os.log` in my answer, which seems to be the same thing.